# Align window to center of the page after changing width and height in ExtJs 4

Tags: extjs4.2

I have a window and my requirement is that I have to change the window's height and width during the `onchange` event of a dropdown.

That works fine but I'm not able to align the window to the center of the browser/page after resize. I had surfed through the net for a while but I'm not able to find a solution.

Can this be done with the resize event of a window? If so, please let me know how to do it. I have not posted any code since I'm not sure where to start with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best place to start is always the docs :)

Have you tried the [`center()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-center) method of `Ext.window.Window`?

Comment: Perfect..That worked fine...Thanks a lot..I used `Ext.getCmp('windowID').center()`

Comment: center really works well.But i think showAt(x, y) can also resolved this issue.